# Batch raster projection conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, batch

I want to do a conversion from WCG to UTM for my 172 Raster. I can't use normal batch because I can't re-arrange again the order of raster in the Table of Content.

Because the result is a random name in the same folder, so I need to do Raster Projection Conversion without changing the name and extension, only the output folder.

How to Batch Raster projection conversion without changing a name and extension only changing the output folder?

Some of Python code:

```
import arcpy, sys

InFolder = r"c:\start"
OutFolder = r"c:\end"
OutSR = r"WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_50S"

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
    arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting " + Ras)
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (InFolder + "\\" + Ras, OutFolder + "\\" + Ras,OutSR)
arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting complete")
```

Comment: Any possibility of doing this in python? You can right click on the tool and select batch but I don't know if that will change the name.

Comment: No, It wont change the name, it generates random name that even different from the 1st raster and I cant rearange my table of content because that strange file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided there is no geographic transformation:

```
import arcpy, sys

InFolder = sys.argv[1]
OutFolder = sys.argv[2]
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(32750) # "WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_50S"

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
    arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting " + Ras)
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (InFolder + "\\" + Ras, OutFolder + "\\" + Ras,OutSR)
arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting complete")
```

Documentation for the tool project raster is here http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007q000000

Instructions on how to make this into a new tool is here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000

For the parameters it's:

```
InFolder is folder/workspace
OutFolder is folder/workspace
OutSR is spatial reference
```

in that order.

The numbers for arcpy.SpatialReference is EPSG (google epsg and the name of the coordinate system). For WGS84 UTM south projections it is 327 and then the zone, so 51 is 32751, 49 is 32749, for WGS84 Geographic it is 4326.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite understand python, is it auto detect input projection?

so for example my infolder = C:\start and outfolder=C:\end and my projection =

Comment: yes, if the projection is defined for the input images all you need do is supply the output projection. Way back in the ArcINFO days you had to supply both input and output and that sometimes lead to data being totally destroyed. Define spatial reference can be batched if it's not set already.

Comment: updated question, I try to input in pyton toolbox, but it's running and do nothing... now there are X mark in python toolbox

Comment: by nothing do you mean that no outputs are being created. The script should print the names of the rasters as it goes, is that happening?

Comment: your code is incorrect: "c:\start" = sys.argv[1] is not right, it should be InFolder = r"c:\start"... it's set *variable* = *value*. Please read the links, they will show you how to make this into a tool.

Comment: updated code, but still got an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 8434, in ProjectRaster
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Project Raster). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter out_coor_system.

Comment: any error message? If you are trying to create the spatial reference in the tool you can't just give the name. See edit. The number is the EPSG for your spatial reference see http://epsg.io/32750

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14939/discussion-between-rikudo-pain-and-michael-miles-stimson).

Comment: Last 2 question how you define those arcpy.SpatialReference(32750) number in the brackets for that projection (because maybe I want to use it for other projection), and how to make it not autorun conversion because its auto convert without I select OK button ? (I delete all the python script when I first create the tool).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the proper code is:

```
import arcpy, sys
InFolder = r"G:\SMGS\rektyfikowane"
OutFolder = r"G:\SMGS\transformed"
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(2180)
arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder
for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
   arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting " + Ras)
   arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (InFolder + "\\" + Ras, OutFolder + "\\" + Ras,OutSR)
arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting complete")
```

There is new spatial reference code where you need to input the EPSG number of coordinate system `arcpy.SpatialReference(2180)`.

Comment: Thank you, yes my mistakes are not using arcpy.SpatialReference().